# Which has a higher order of growth, c.n.(log (base 1.5) n) or d.(n^(log (base 1.5) 2))

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, recurrence, clrs

I was looking at an example from a book. The final equation comes to ( c⋅n log (base 1.5) n)+  d.(n^(log (base 1.5) 2)) . I assume that the second function has a higher order of growth. As it evaluates to roughly           n ^ 1.71, but the example choses the first function as the one with a higher order of growth. Why is this?

Comment: I agree with your reasoning; might be best to shun that book --- unless you misread or misquoted that question.

Answer (score 0):

The book is right. Let's see why.

I will use `log` instead of `log(base 1.5)` to simplify the notation. Then we have to prove the validity of

```
a*n*log(n) > n^b                (1)
```

for a value of `b` which, according to your calculations, satisfies

```
1 < b < 2                       (2)
```

(the constant `a` above is nothing but `c/d`)

Now let's divide both sides of (1) by `n`:

```
a*log(n) > n^(b-1)
```

or

```
a*log(n) > n^r                  (3)
```

where `r = b-1` satisfies (see (2))

```
0 < r < 1                       (4)
```

Now, the derivative of `x^r` w.r.t. `x` is

```
r*x^(r-1)
```

or

```
r/x^s
```

with `s = 1-r > 0` because of (4). Since `x^s` is increasing, `r/x^s` is decreasing, while `a*log(x)` is increasing because `log` is. This means that the function on the left of (3) is increasing, while the one on the right decreasing. This is why the inequality at (3) will eventually be valid (i.e., will hold for `n` large enough).

Comment: Thank you so much! I had just started learning about analysis and time complexity, did not even realize we can use derivatives to come up with a solution.